# Looking for sound effects of old vintage cars, circa 1950's to 1960's

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, car, vintage, south-africa

I am part of a post crew doing the sound for a feature documentary, set between the 1950's and the 1960's. Throughout the movie there is a wide variety of period cars ranging from army jeeps, to ford pic ups, sedans and coupes. The director has a focus on the authenticity of the cars' sounds and as such we are looking for well recorded clips of these cars, ranging from idle, pull offs, accelerations, driving speeds, doors, and road surfaces.

If there is anyone that knows of someone I can contact, that has clips like these or even of someone in the Gauteng region of South Africa in possession of these cars for us to record, please let me know.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the guys at sounddogs.com just did a bunch of field recording in Cuba, where lots of old '50s cars are still in use. You might contact them and see what they've got.